# Check for missing CSS classes

Tags: css, webpack, saas

Hi is there a way to check on a project for missing css-class definitions ?

To explain what's my intended usage:

Let's say we rely on a design system package which hold some css class definitions, built on SAAS.
Upon updating this package I would like to be able to determine whether any of the classes that we were previously using had been removed for instance, which would, in turn, break our app silently.

I was thinking of some sort of webpack plugin, but so far could only find checks for unused classes and not the other way around.

Thanks

Comment: You could diff the two CSS files to see which classes have been removed from the CSS and then search your code for those strings.

Comment: Bryce, that's what we are doing but I meant in an automated fashion so that we could put on a ci pipeline to validate the whole project after a dependency upgrade

Comment: Depending on what you're using for automated testing, you should be able to write that up reasonably easily. You might need to generate the list of whats "missing" manually but that should be rare. Then you can use that list in your tests.